# property envMap removed from shader cube in THREE.JS r146

Tags: three.js, shader

the envMap property has now totally gone away in the cube shader lib in three.js rel 146. I'd like to ask if there is a workaround ? Thanks

Comment: cube shader lib is a shader from the three.js shader library. It was initially done for creating a skybox. I think there is now Scene.background but this does not solve my issue.

Comment: name of the shader is cube

Comment: three.js doc on shader lib is not populated. Some reference here

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r59/src/renderers/WebGLShaders.js#L1936

Comment: uniforms now only includes tCube and tFlip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with `tCube` instead. Check out the following live demo for more details.

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;

init().then( render );

async function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000 );
    camera.position.z = 1;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    const path = 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/cube/pisa/';
    const format = '.png';
    const urls = [
      path + 'px' + format, path + 'nx' + format,
      path + 'py' + format, path + 'ny' + format,
      path + 'pz' + format, path + 'nz' + format
    ];
    
    const loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
    const cubeMap = await loader.loadAsync( urls );

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1000, 1000, 1000 );
    const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
      uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( THREE.ShaderLib['cube'].uniforms ),
      vertexShader: THREE.ShaderLib['cube'].vertexShader,
      fragmentShader: THREE.ShaderLib['cube'].fragmentShader,
      side: THREE.BackSide,
      depthTest: false,
      depthWrite: false
    } );
    
    material.uniforms.tCube.value = cubeMap;

    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function render() {

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.148/build/three.min.js"></script>
```